# Stanford NNDep parser: features used

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

In regards to Stanford’s neural network dependency parser[*̦](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml) which features are used during training and testing phases? In practice, which columns in a CONLL[ᶸ](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/format)[ˣ](http://ilk.uvt.nl/conll/#dataformat) formatted data set could be substituted with **_** without the parser loosing any accuracy when training? Which columns are never read?

Certainly `ID`, `FORM` and `HEAD` (columns # **1**, **2** & **7**) are a must, as most likely are `U/C-POSTAG` (# **4**) and `DEPREL` (# **8**). But how about the columns `LEMMA`, `(X)-POSTAG` and `FEATS` (# **3**, **5** & **6**)? Do they help while training, or whether the treebank contains any information in these is irrelevant for the parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the current implementation, we only use the following fields. My column indexing begins from 1.

- `FORM` (column 2)
- `UPOSTAG` (column 4) [^1]
- `HEAD` (column 7)
- `DEPREL` (column 8)

[^1]: If parsing with coarse part-of-speech tags (`-cPOS`), we read column 5 instead.

Everything else can be null, so long as you don't break the CoNLL format (i.e., still include a `_` in the null column).

See exactly which columns we read here: [`edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.Util.loadConllFile`](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/nndep/Util.java#L165). Note these are the same for both CoNLL-X and CoNLL-U representations.

Comment: Appreciate this comprehensive answer.